# How to get all files from a specific folder and store them in DB, django

Tags: python, django

```
class Documents(models.Model):
   file = models.FileField()
```

I have got a folder called media in the root. It contains multiple files (pdf's). Can I automatically store them in the table called Documents.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found already an answer

```
import os

for filename in os.listdir("..."):
    if filename.endswith(".pdf"): 
        Documents.objects.create(file=filename)
    else:
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know a direct link between files in a filesystem and a django model filefield but you can get all files in a tree (even recursiv) and loop through them e.g.:

```
path = 'C:/ ....'
file = '*.txt'

for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, file), recursive = True):
    # here create file entry in your model
```

maybe this helps